# Copyright mitthesis

Tags: templates, copyright

I'm trying to turn off the long copyright "The author hereby grants to MIT permission to reproduce and to distribute publicly paper and electronic copies of this thesis document in whole or in part in any medium now known or hereafter created." in the mitthesis latex template. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Any pointer for the class?

Answer (score 5):

If the class is the one downloaded from http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/, then it's sufficient to add

```
\renewcommand{\permission}{}
```

in your document preamble.

Answer (score 3):

As an update to this topic, an newer latex template for an MIT thesis was released in 2023, here:  https://ctan.org/pkg/mitthesis

The copyright permission mentioned is required for theses submitted to MIT, but for other uses the permission can be omitted by using a star form `\maketitle*`, rather than the standard form `\maketitle`.

Again, that permission statement is required when you submit a thesis for an MIT degree.